# StdDraw stop repainting suddenly

Tags: stddraw

I'm developing a game using StdDraw in Bluej, but when I'm testing the game, it suddenly stop repainting the screen and it doesn't do anything else.
I'm sure the problem isn't and infinite loop because I have debbuged the code and it is still running well, changing variables and all that things.
I don't have idea what is happening :(
Does anyone has a suggestion?
Thanks :)
(Sorry for bad english)